# CSRF failure in custom mongoose pre-hook (Keystone.js)

Tags: keystonejs

using keystone LocalFile type to handle image uploads. similar to the Cloudinary `autoCleanup` option, I want to be able to delete the uploaded file itself, in addition to the corresponding mongo entry when deleting entries through the admin ui.

in this case, I want to delete an "Album", and it's corresponding album cover.

`Album.schema.pre('remove', function(next){
  var path = this._original.album_cover.path + "/" + this._original.album_cover.filename
  fs.unlink(path, function () {
    console.log('deleted');
  })`

I get "CSRF failure" when using the `fs` module. I thought all CSRF protection was handled internally with Keystone.

Anyone know of a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Took a 10 minute break and came back and it seems to be working now. I also found this, which seems to be the explanation.

"Moreover double check your session timeout. In my dev settings the session duration is set to 3 minutes. So, if I end up editing something for more than that time, Keystone will return a CSRF error on save because the new session (generate in the meantime) invalidates the old token."

https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/1330